# Error: Could not find the correct Provider<XBloc> above this YDetails Widget

Tags: flutter, dart, provider, flutter-provider

I am trying to use bloc in my code for firestore database

**HandleSubscription method**

```
  void handleSubscription() {

    context.read<SubscriptionBloc>().saveNewSubscription("123", "abc");
   
  }
```

**Widget build:**

```
    @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       handleSubscription();

       return Scaffold(
      ...
    );
    }
```

I have SubscriptionBloc code but I don't want to share as my problem is not related with this code.

I am getting this error:

> Exception has occurred. ProviderNotFoundException (Error: Could not
> find the correct Provider above this ArticleDetails
> Widget
>
> This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include
> the provider of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:
>
> - You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.   To fix, perform a hot-restart.
> - The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.
>
>   Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route,
>   then   other routes will not be able to access that provider.
> - You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.
>
>   Make sure that ArticleDetails is under your
>   MultiProvider/Provider.   This usually happens when
>   you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.
>
>   For example, instead of:
>
>   ````
>     return Provider<Example>(
>       create: (_) => Example(),
>       // Will throw a ProviderNotFoundError, because `context` is associated
>       // to the widget that is the parent of `Provider<Example>`
>       child: Text(context.watch<Example>().toString()),
>     );   }   ```
>
>   consider using `builder` like so:
>
>   ```   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>     return Provider<Example>(
>       create: (_) => Example(),
>       // we use `builder` to obtain a new `BuildContext` that has access to the provider
>       builder: (context, child) {
>         // No longer throws
>         return Text(context.watch<Example>().toString());
>       }
>     );   }   ```
>   ````
>
> If none of these solutions work, consider asking for help on
> StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter )

Comment: Can you also show the code where you have provided the bloc?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the `BuildContext` used in `handleSubscription()` actually has access to `SubscriptionBloc`.

I.e., you are trying to read a provider as soon as the widget builds. Consider deferring this to a later lifecycle method like [`didChangeDependencies`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/didChangeDependencies.html) or utilize a [`Builder` widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Builder-class.html) to make sure the context you are using is a descendant of your provider.

---

`Builder` approach:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Builder(
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        handleSubscription();
        return // Rest of your UI
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

That `Builder` would create a new `BuildContext` that is a direct child of `Scaffold`, which should ideally be under your `Provider<SubscriptionBloc>` if you have structured your widget tree correctly.

---

[`didChangeDependencies` method](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/didChangeDependencies.html) approach:

That method is called when a dependency of the `State` object changes.
In your case, if your widget relies on an [`InheritedWidget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html) (which is what [`Provider`](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) uses under the hood), `didChangeDependencies` is called whenever that inherited widget is updated.

```dart
class YourWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _YourWidgetState createState() => _YourWidgetState();
}

class _YourWidgetState extends State<YourWidget> {
  
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    handleSubscription();
  }

  void handleSubscription() {
    final bloc = Provider.of<SubscriptionBloc>(context, listen: false);
    bloc.saveNewSubscription("123", "abc");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      // Your UI here
    );
  }
}
```

The `handleSubscription` method is moved into `didChangeDependencies`.
The `Provider.of<SubscriptionBloc>(context, listen: false)` call fetches the `SubscriptionBloc` from the nearest ancestor in the widget tree. Since `didChangeDependencies` is called after `initState` and every time the widget rebuilds due to a change in an `InheritedWidget`, it is generally a safe place to access your `Provider`.

That approach avoids accessing the `Provider` directly within the `build` method, giving the widget a chance to complete its initial build process.

Answer (score 1):

If `SubscriptionBloc` is going to be used in all over the app, you should create an instance of bloc in `main.dart` like this:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) =>
          SubscriptionBloc(),
      lazy: false,
      child: MaterialApp(),
    );
  }
```

or if `SubscriptionBloc` in going to be used only in one place, create in just in that place like this example:

```
class PageUsingBloc extends StatelessWidget {
  const PageUsingBloc({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => SubscriptionBloc(),
      child: const _View(),
    );
  }
}

class _View extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //so here context.read<SubscriptionBloc>() works
    context.read<SubscriptionBloc>().saveNewSubscription("123", "abc");

    return Scaffold(
    ...
    );
  }
}
```

In both cases the bloc is created and `Could not find the correct Provider is solved`

Answer (score 0):

the error says the provider not found means you haven't provided the provider above the widget

Suppose your widget/screen is `ArticleDetails` in which you're calling `handleSubscription` method, so what have you to do is wrap your `ArticleDetails Widget/Screen` with `BlocProvider` which will provide the scope of `SubscriptionBloc` to `ArticleDetails`. For example

```
const BlocProvider(
    create: (context) => SubscriptionBloc(),
    child: ArticleDetails(),
),
```

And the Article widget is

```
class ArticleDetails extends StatefulWidget {
  const ArticleDetails({super.key});

  @override
  State<ArticleDetails> createState() => _ArticleDetailsState();
}

class _ArticleDetailsState extends State<ArticleDetails> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    handleSubscription();
    super.initState();
  }

  void handleSubscription() {
    context.read<SubscriptionBloc>().saveNewSubscription("123", "abc");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Placeholder();
  }
}
```